# Datamapper, Sinatra, Haml : attaching and rendering Comments from a post

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml, datamapper

I have a model Ticket which `has n` Comments belonging to it (many to one relationship).

The issue is that I can not render any of the comments nor does the form post the comments to the database.

I can kinda sorta do this from irb. I can add comments to tickets.comments, but I cannot pull individual comments - I can pull up the collection but have not figured out how to do anything with it. It is a Class: DataMapper::Associations::OneToMany::Collection and documentation says "A Collection should act like an Array in every way"

So 2 issues needing reading and input:

1) posting from the web form
2) iterating over and rendering the collection through haml, which I can't seem to do.

More gory details:

I have a Sinatra method that pulls up

```
get '/:thisticket' do
   @ticket=Ticket.first(:slug=>params[:slug])
   if @ticket
       haml :showticket
```

Haml template

```
%div{:class => "ticket"}
 %h1
  = @ticket.slug

= @ticket.comments.all              (returns the # symbol to any html page)

- @ticket.comments.all do |comment|
 %h4
  = comment.a_comment
 %h4
  = comment.created_at
 %h4
  = comment.id                       (this block shows nothing on a rendered page) 

%center
 %form{:action => "/#{@thisticket.slug}/update", :enctype => "text/plain", :method => "post"}
 comments
 %br/
 %textarea{:id => "a_comment",:name => "a_comment", :rows => "5"}
 :preserve
 %br/
 %input{:type => "submit", :value => "post"}/
```

Comment: At this point I realize the method all might not be what I need to do, but it seemed an apt method originally.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone paying attention or having the same:

This works

Sinatra

```
get '/:thisticket' do
   @ticket=Ticket.first(:thisticket=>params[:thisticket])
   @comments=@ticket.comments.all(:order => [ :created_at.desc ])
   if @ticket
       haml :showticket
```

Haml

```
@comments.each do |comment|
comment.comment
```

etc, etc, et. al.